# Android Notification has no sound nor vibration (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, service, notifications

My App is running as Service. As long as the service is active the user may receive notifications. The notifications work except that no matter what I do it does not send a sound or vibration. For testing purposes I have hardcoded the sound and vibration like this:

```
                setSound(soundUri, myAudioAttributes)
                enableVibration(true)
                vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(500, 500, 500)
```

Note that when I test the sound or vibration that my phone's setting is set to either of those.

Full Code below:

```
class NotificationComponent(val context: Context) : LifecycleService(),
CoroutineScope by ServiceScope() {

private val notificationManager =
    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

private val channelName = context.getString(R.string.notification_name)
private val channelId = context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_id)

val soundSetting = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
private var isSoundEnabled = false

val vibrationSetting = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
private var isVibrationEnabled = false

private val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

private val myAudioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
    .build()

init {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        withService {
            notification.soundSetting.observe(this) { s ->
                isSoundEnabled = s
                Timber.d("preference sound enabled $s")
            }
            notification.vibrationSetting.observe(this) { v ->
                isVibrationEnabled = v
                Timber.d("preference vibration enabled $v")
            }
        }
        createNotificationChannel(channelName)
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun createNotificationChannel(channelName: String) =
    with(context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager) {
        createNotificationChannel(
            NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            ).apply {
                setSound(soundUri, myAudioAttributes)
                enableVibration(true)
                lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
                vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(500, 500, 500)
            }
        )
    }

fun createAndSendNotification(
    title: String,
    content: String,
    notificationID: Int,
    type: NotificationType
): Notification {
    val name = context.getString(R.string.notification_name)
    val builder: Notification.Builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createNotificationChannel(name)
        Notification.Builder(context, channelId)
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        Notification.Builder(context)
    }
    builder.setContentTitle(title)
    builder.setContentText(content)
    builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    builder.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    }
    when (type) {
        NotificationType.ALARM -> {
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm)
            builder.setContentIntent(createPendingIntent(type, context))
        }
        NotificationType.CHAT -> {
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_chat)
            builder.setContentIntent(createPendingIntent(type, context))
        }
    }
    builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(DigitalMeetsApplication.appContext)) {
        notify(notificationID, builder.build())
    }
    return builder.build()
}
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

I tried other topics to fix my issue, but none seem to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just checking, but your phone definitely isn't set to Do Not Disturb or similar? Are other apps' notifications working? Does this work on an emulator (the sound at least)? The notification channel hasn't been set to no sound and no vibrations by the user? Are you reusing the same ``notificationId`` and not dismissing it between updates? Because ``setAlertOnlyOnce`` is for silently updating an existing notification

Comment: It's weird. On my S20 it's always silent. And on a S8+ it always sends a sound and a vibration with the same codebase. Even if i set enableVibration to false and set the vibration pattern to 0L and setSound to null,null.

Comment: It looks like I found the issue. The channel ID needs to be changed everytime the user changes his settings if he/she wants to enable/disbale sound or vibration. Only then the same notification channel that has already existed won't be reused.

Comment: Notification channels are basically meant to put control in the hands of the user - when you create a channel, you can give it some default settings, but you can't modify it after that (except for things like titles). The user can set it to no vibration, no sound, and your app can't force it. You shouldn't really be creating new channels to get around that, if that's what you're doing (it's considered spammy behaviour and the settings will warn the user about it). Better to check current settings and advise the user to change them, or use `Ringtone`s and `Vibrator`s to manually notify IMO

Comment: Thanks, I was having a wrong approach then. Will change it!

Comment: Is it possible to enable or disable a notification sound during runtime? After the app started and the channel has been created I can't seem to change it depending on user settings input.

Comment: You should be able to make the notification silent with https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setSilent(boolean) and then you can handle your own sound and vibration stuff. And you can use ``NotificationManagerCompat#getNotificationChannel`` to get your channel, and use things like ``NotificationChannel#shouldVibrate`` to check the user's settings to work out what you need to do